# MODX: where are new_folder_permissions and new_file_permissions?

Tags: configuration, modx

Those are asked during the installation, but are not anywhere in config files\tables to change afterwards

EDIT:

The changelog states the following:

- [#MODX-760], [#MODX-1080], [#MODX-1528] Added setup option to set new_file_permissions and new_folder_permissions in welcome view
- [#MODX-760], [#MODX-1528] Removed new_file_permissions and new_folder_permissions system settings from setup

Seems kinda weird to me to do that... I am still in need to change them, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that these should be in your MODX System Settings although I wasn't able to locate them in any of my own MODX installs (all Revo 2.1+). There's a chance they might be redundant or are for some reason not being properly created during installation (in which case it might be an installer bug).

You might be able to override them by adding those settings, like so:

```
Key:    new_folder_permissions
Value:  0755
```

Do that and then try creating a new folder using the File Manager. Let us know if the correct permissions are then being used. If so I'll look at opening up a bug report for the installer.

Comment: `new_folder_permissions` works for me (MODX Revolution 2.5.0-pl) but `new_file_permissions` does not.

Answer (score 2):

They are not in System Settings, as they default to the PHP umask values, as they should. If you want to override them, you can do so by adding the settings "new_file_permissions" or "new_folder_permissions" to your System Settings.

Comment: If permissions other than the default are specified during the install process, would these then be added to System Settings by the installer?

Comment: I have tried doing so as one of the posters already suggested, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

apache/webuser needs to write to:
core/cache
core/export
core/config/config.inc.php [change back after install]
core/packages
core/components
assets/components

*EDIT* Sorry, take a look here: core/model/modx/processors/system/filesys/folder/create.php
 they appear to be hard coded in that file.

Comment: The question is about the location of new_folder_permissions and new_file_permissions system settings. How is what you wrote relevant?